# Run user-data script on EC2 Ubuntu instance in the cloud-init.service rather than the cloud-final.service

Tags: cloud-init

I have a task to reduce the latency of EC2 instances' system initializations. I noticed that the user data script is run in the cloud-final.service, but is it possible to run it early? For example have it run in cloud-init.service.

Didn't find a way to do so.